# Изменить значение JSON в массиве [RethinkDB]

Tags: java, база-данных

В RethinkDB есть строка формата:

```
{
'name': 'Hilgert',
'info': [
        {
            'a': 123123
            'b': 123124
        },
        {
            'a': 123135
            'b': 123136
        },
        {
            'a': 12364
            'b': -1
        }
    ]
}
```

Требуется найти Объект в массиве info, у которого b равен -1, и изменить его на нужное значение. Как это сделать?

Библиотека - Официальная, с сайта RethinkDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готовое решение, может понадобится кому.

```
Cursor<HashMap<String, Object>> s = r.table("plays").filter(row -> 
row.g("name").eq(elem.getPlayer().getName())).run(conn);

HashMap<String, Object> field = s.next();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> infoList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
Object>>) field.get("info");

for (HashMap<String, Object> info : infoList) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(info.get("quit").toString()) != -1) continue;
    info.put("quit", Utils.getUNIX());
}

r.table("plays").filter(row -> 
row.g("name").eq(elem.getPlayer().getName())).update(r.hashMap("info", field)).run(conn);
```